# fadeIn/ fadeOut on hover not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few images on my site with a css opacity animation and I wanted to show a text on each image on hover.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <img src="http://www.theblogazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/20140414-The-Blogazine-Salone-Goodbye-03.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 id="img-title">Projekt 1<h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-5">
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/fbcca32890631d26020608e240fe4602/tumblr_mn4xq4ntLI1qkjjfoo1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
    <h2 id = "img-title">Projekt 2<h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-5">
    <img src="http://45.media.tumblr.com/1b793888369840a9e1b9f2f739d32767/tumblr_nuofw201Uk1safpwto1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
    <h2 id = "img-title">Projekt 3<h2>

    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zONV6q4OL._SY450_.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2 id = "img-title">Projekt 4<h2>

    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://www.themekongclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/10.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2 id = "img-title">Projekt 5<h2>

    </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my jQuery (I wanted to try it out for one image first):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('col-sm-7').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find("#img-title").fadeIn(250);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find("#img-title").fadeOut(250);
        }
    );
};
```

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IDs should be unique per page.

Comment: `.col-sm-7` <- the dot is missing

Comment: ` $('col-sm-7')` should be  `$('.col-sm-7')` DOT for class selector

Comment: I followed all sugestions and it's still not working ;((

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle so I can understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your HTML markup,

- `<h2>` not being properly closed
- ID's `#` must be unique
- <strike>div's not well closed (or closed in wrong places) - *let me know if I did the markup as you wished.*</strike>

Plus your JS had mistakes, such as:

- `$('col-sm-7')` should be `$('.col-sm-7')`
- switched `fadeIn/fadeOut`, since `.img-title` is already displayed, so a `fadeIn` on first `hover` doesn't do anything

So here is a full snippet:

#### Snippet

```js
$('.col-sm-7').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeOut(250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeIn(250);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <img src="http://www.theblogazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/20140414-The-Blogazine-Salone-Goodbye-03.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 1</h2>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/fbcca32890631d26020608e240fe4602/tumblr_mn4xq4ntLI1qkjjfoo1_500.gif" class="img-responsive" />
          <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <img src="http://45.media.tumblr.com/1b793888369840a9e1b9f2f739d32767/tumblr_nuofw201Uk1safpwto1_500.gif" class="img-responsive" />
          <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zONV6q4OL._SY450_.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="http://www.themekongclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/10.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 5</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** OP's Comment

> it just screwed my gallery completely

So using your **own** untouched HTML markup (only fixing `<h2>` not being closed and you have to change to id`#` to classes`.`, because ID is unique. ), here is a snippet:

#### Snippet

```js
$('#proj-1,#proj-2,#proj-3,#proj-4,#proj-5').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeOut(250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeIn(250);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="proj-1" class="col-sm-7">
        <img src="http://www.theblogazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/20140414-The-Blogazine-Salone-Goodbye-03.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="proj-2" class="col-sm-5">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/fbcca32890631d26020608e240fe4602/tumblr_mn4xq4ntLI1qkjjfoo1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="proj-3" class="col-sm-5">
        <img src="http://45.media.tumblr.com/1b793888369840a9e1b9f2f739d32767/tumblr_nuofw201Uk1safpwto1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 3</h2>

      </div>
      <div id="proj-4" class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zONV6q4OL._SY450_.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 4</h2>

      </div>
      <div id="proj-5" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://www.themekongclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/10.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h2 class="img-title">Projekt 5</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should also mention, that you switched fadein/fadeout, since .img-title is already displayed, so a fade in on first hover doesn't do anything... ;)

Comment: Thanks, added the info.

Comment: it just screwed my gallery completely ;c

Comment: @Dorota the HTML markup? If so I'm gonna redo the HTML markup using yours then.

Comment: now my first text is located below the image and the rest on the image. no animations effects.

Comment: Can you show the link? Because snippet here is working

Comment: @Dorota just want to hover the `col-sm-7` ? sorry for delay but I was lunching

Comment: I want to hover all <h2>, just did the first one to see if it will be working

Comment: i updated it, you can check out the link, still not working properly. can it be that someting in the css stands in the way?

Comment: @Dorota you definitely have some HTML errors (I'm seeing total 32), such as `no document type declaration; implying "<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>"` and you are not using the  the js code provided in the snippet., plus you have CSS and Files loading locally from your PC, that won't work

Comment: I did some changes, files are loaded not from PC, i added the doctype, fixed some bugs, but that doesn't fix the hover.

Comment: well much better, from 32 to 9 errors, so where you have this:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` delete the `<link ...`because you already have on top. and in order to make the `hover` working you need to have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your `<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/javascript" href="js.js">` otherwise it wont work the js file.

Comment: @Dorota did you see my comment?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I followed your instructions. But still nothing :)

Comment: My bad! this: `<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/javascript" href="js.js">` is wrong! should be `<script src="js.js"></script>` and inside your .js file you are missing a `});` because you are using `document.ready`

Comment: @Dorota you still have minor HTML  markup errors but won't influence the hover. with my above comment it will work I've tested on the fly on your site.

Comment: @Dorota you didn't make my first change, this one: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="js.js">` is wrong! should be `<script src="js.js"></script>`

Comment: it works now, thanks a looooot!  it animates, but.. I wanted the text to appear on hover, and it disappears instead. what should I change in my js?

Comment: @Dorota add `$('.img-title').hide();` before the `hover`change `fadeIn` to `fadeOut` and `fadeOut` to `fadeIn` then, and if my answer and all the afterwards debugging helped you fixing your issues, please make sure you mark this answer as accepted

Comment: I ad to change my js code completely, but now it works fine :) Thanks a lot for your help, have a nice day!

Comment: @Dorota your code (I just saw now, it is not working in Firefox), the one I gave you was working cross browser, here is the full code : `$(document).ready(function() {
$('.img-title').hide();
$('#proj-1,#proj-2,#proj-3,#proj-4,#proj-5').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeIn(250);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeOut(250);
  });});` simply copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

there is some mistaken in selector and even you did not close h2. and you need to use different ID.
working demo https://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderPatel/4vffxqb7/1/

```js
$(function () {
  $('.col-sm-7').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find("h2").fadeIn(250);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find("h2").fadeOut(250);
        }
    );
})
```

```css
img{
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "gallery">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-sm-7">
        <img src="http://www.theblogazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/20140414-The-Blogazine-Salone-Goodbye-03.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h2>Projekt 1</h2>
      </div>
<div class = "col-sm-5">
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/fbcca32890631d26020608e240fe4602/tumblr_mn4xq4ntLI1qkjjfoo1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
<h2>Projekt 2</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-sm-5">
<img src="http://45.media.tumblr.com/1b793888369840a9e1b9f2f739d32767/tumblr_nuofw201Uk1safpwto1_500.gif" class="img-responsive">
<h2>Projekt 3</h2>

</div>
<div class = "col-sm-3">
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zONV6q4OL._SY450_.jpg" class="img-responsive">
<h2>Projekt 4</h2>

</div>
<div class = "col-sm-4">
<img src="http://www.themekongclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/10.jpg" class="img-responsive">
<h2>Projekt 5</h2>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: added the dot but nothing changed